# How to successfully compile NSClassFromString in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Code below can't compile successfully.I also attached a screenshot for reference!

```
func getXibViewWithClassNameString(classNameString:String)->AnyObject?{
    let projectName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as? String
    let MyClass:AnyClass = NSClassFromString(projectName! + "." + classNameString)!

    var viewArray:NSArray?
    var xibView:AnyClass?
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(classNameString, owner: nil, topLevelObjects: &viewArray)
    for viewInArray in viewArray ?? [] {
        if (viewInArray is MyClass){
        xibView = viewInArray as MyClass
        }
    }
    return xibView
}
```

[screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXVmD.png)

Comment: `NSClassFromString` is pretty *objective-c-ish*. In Swift there are better ways to check types at **compile** time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key mistake here is that you can't `as` or `is` check on a dynamic type. You need to have a static type, known at compile time, to use that. As pointum notes, you need to use `isKind(of:)` or `isMember(of:)` on the underlying NSObject instead. Here's how I would recommend doing that:

```
func firstXibViewOfClass(named classNameString: String) -> NSView? {
    // Create an AnyClass object
    guard let projectName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleExecutable"] as? String,
        let myClass = NSClassFromString(projectName + "." + classNameString)
        else {
            return nil
    }

    // Load the nib
    var topLevelObjects: NSArray?
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(classNameString, owner: nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)

    // Convert it to NSObjects (since they all are going to be)
    guard let nsObjectArray = topLevelObjects as? [NSObject] else { return nil }

    // Find the first matching view and return it as an NSView if possible
    return nsObjectArray.first(where: {
        $0.isKind(of: myClass)  // Or isMember(of:) if you want to be strict
    }) as? NSView
}
```

If you don't need to include subclasses, though, you might want to just check the classname directly. This gets rid of all the AnyClass stuff:

```
func firstXibViewOfClass(named classNameString: String) -> NSView? {
    // Load the nib
    var topLevelObjects: NSArray?
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(classNameString, owner: nil, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects)

    // Convert it to NSObjects (since they all are going to be)
    guard let nsObjectArray = topLevelObjects as? [NSObject] else { return nil }

    // Find the first matching view and return it as an NSView if possible
    return nsObjectArray.first(where: { $0.className == classNameString }) as? NSView
}
```

You could of course just return `AnyObject?`, but the name of the method suggests that you expect it to be a view, so you should enforce that or rename the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can test with

```
if viewInArray.isKind(of: MyClass) { ... }
```

or

```
if viewInArray.isMember(of: MyClass) { ... } // strict class match
```

But I don’t think you can cast to a class that is not available at compile time to Swift. You won’t be able to directly call any of its methods anyway. You can cast it to some `NSObject` subclass and send arbitrary (not defined at compile time) messages to it, though.